# VS-Code Extension: vscode.window.activeTextEditor == undefined

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I wrote an Visual Studio Code extension.
Based on this example:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/previewhtml-sample

```ts
var editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
if (!editor) {
    console.log("No open text editor");
}
```

This works fine if i open a 2MB File.
But not if the file is 5MB or larger.

But if I copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) a 10MB into a new editor it will work and is prety fast.
Has anyone an idea what kind of limitation this is?

Or is there perhaps a work around by some how let user choose a file in command.
To directly read the file?

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me. Can you please open an issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new

Comment: @MattBierner done: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32118

Comment: Keep in mind also that there is no active editor when one of the preview html tabs has the focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was addressed upstream in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32118)

The root cause was that VS Code did not properly create text editors for files over a certain size. That size limit has since increased but you still may run into this limitation for very large files

Comment: Actualy i hsow a warning to the user if the text file is to big:https://github.com/GreenRover/hibernate-log-analyser/blob/master/src/extension.ts#L40