# Obtain collated search results for large files in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using the [Find All in File](https://github.com/bnason-nf/findallinfile) VSCode extension and I have a large file ~65MB in which I need to perform a regex search and list all the results, which is what the extension is for. But it fails with an error:

```
ERROR: No active editor document
```

[image]

Trying to debug this, it seems this is because of [`getActiveDocument()`](https://github.com/bnason-nf/findallinfile/blob/a36fbfac0d4141c8c5b82b3491e057441353fe37/src/extension.ts#L11) returning `undefined` which then leads to [`outputSink.noDocument()`](https://github.com/bnason-nf/findallinfile/blob/a36fbfac0d4141c8c5b82b3491e057441353fe37/src/findAllInFile.ts#L298) leading to the [`error_no_document`](https://github.com/bnason-nf/findallinfile/blob/a36fbfac0d4141c8c5b82b3491e057441353fe37/src/treeDataProvider.ts#L107) error which is translated as [`No active editor document`](https://github.com/bnason-nf/findallinfile/blob/8e77fcdff11b57525f83d02aca6d61e94e2e4e83/package.nls.json#L10).

I found that there is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45544788/1851678) related to large files not having an active editor due to VSCode restrictions.

So the question is, how do I search for regex in large files and see the collated output in one place, just like Notepad++ etc. It works if I copy the file contents to a new file and *then* search in the file.

Comment: I ran in the same problem with my extension, I made an issue and it was closed with the comment: **Extensions are not allowed to open files >50MB. This will not be changed.**

Comment: @rioV8 True. [This](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/909318736552b321d78da6d2ae65d4838800ae5e) is the change that bumped it after discussions [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32118#issuecomment-325300199). Seems quite arbitrary to disallow that. I'm not sure why that wasn't left as configurable by the user.

Comment: You can write a python script that does the search, start the script with a Task, ask the thing to search with an input variable or use [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable), parse the result with a problem matcher and view list in PROBLEMS panel

Comment: what does this extension do what the standard **Regex Find** can't

Comment: @rioV8 It grabs all the results of the Regex Find and dumps it in one place, unlike the Regex Find where one needs to keep iterating over each search hit.  At least, that's how I do it. This plugin helps in looking at all the search results in one place.  Is there a better way that you have?

Comment: Can you just do a search across files but scope it to just the current file?  You can copy those search results or open them in a new editor.  My extension makes doing the search with the scope pretty easy.  There may be a limit on the maxSearchResults that you hit for which there is a setting.

Comment: @Mark That's a very neat workaround for my situation! It works.

Comment: I see I actually forgot to name the extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview